# How to use MongoDB as unique/enumeration store

Tags: c#, mongodb, enumeration, bigdata

This seems to be like a common use case... but somehow I cannot get it working.

I'm attempting to use MongoDB as an enumeration store with unique items. I've created a collection with a byte[] Id (the unique ID) and a timestamp (a long, used for enumeration). The store is quite big (terabytes) and distributed among different servers. I am able to re-build the store from scratch currently, since I'm still in the testing phase.

What I want to do is two things:

1. Create a unique id for each item that I insert. This basically means that if I insert the same ID twice, MongoDB will detect this and give an error. This approach seems to work fine.
2. Continuously enumerate the store for new items by other processes. The approach I took was to add a second index to InsertID and used a high precision timestamp on this along with the server id and a counter (just to make it unique and ascending).

In the best scenario this would mean that the enumerator would keep track of an index cursor for every server. From what I've learned from mongodb query processing I expected this behavior. However, when I try to execute the code (below) it seems to take forever to get anything.

```
        long lastid = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            DateTime first = DateTime.UtcNow;
            foreach (var item in collection.FindAllAs<ContentItem>().OrderBy((a)=>(a.InsertId)).Take(100))
            {
                lastid = item.InsertId;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Took {0:0.00} for 100", (DateTime.UtcNow - first).TotalSeconds);
        }
```

I've read about cursors, but am unsure if they fulfill the requirements when new items are inserted into the store.

As I said, I'm not bound to any table structure or something like that... the only things that are important is that I can get new items over time and without getting duplicate items.

-Stefan.

Comment: I am not sure if I have got your question! But, why don't you let mongodb generate the uniqueId. It already does that!

Comment: What you would need though is to ensure that a string is not being enumerated twice OR said in another way two ids should not have the same value!

Comment: It sounds like you are using sharding (*multiple computers*). What is your shard key here? How many servers do you have? Querying by a secondary index across multiple servers could be your problem, but I would need more details about your configuration.

Comment: @Ozair: I generate a unique id because i use that for duplicate detection. (1) The ID is basically an MD5 hash of the content that I insert; if I insert it twice, it will collide and give an error -- which is correct.

Comment: @GatesVP Yes you are correct: we use sharding with 14 instances of MongoDB at the moment (that might grow in the future). The shard key is the MD5 hash. The secondary key is the InsertId. In other words, I do expect an enumeration query to go to 14 servers. Still, 20 seconds for a query with 100 results is way too long; the behavior that I expect is that the query goes to all servers, grabs ~10 results (you can easily deduce that from the statistics, since each server holds more or less an equal amount of documents), merge them and sends them back to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I figured it out... more or less...

I created the query manually and ended up with something like this:

> db.documents.find({ "InsertId" : { "$gt" : NumberLong("2020374866209304106") } }).limit(10).sort({ "InsertId" : 1 });

The LINQ query I put in the question doesn't generate this query. After some digging in the code I found that it should be this LINQ query:

> foreach (var item in collection.AsQueryable().Where((a)=>(a.InsertId > lastid)).OrderBy((a) => (a.InsertId)).Take(100))

The AsQueryable() seems to be the key to execute the rewriting of LINQ to MongoDB queries.

This gives results, but still they appeared to be slow (4 secs for 10 results, 30 for 100). However, when I added 'explain()' I noticed '0 millis' in the query execution.

I stopped the process doing bulk inserts and tada, it works, and fast. In other words: the issues I was having were due to the locking behavior of MongoDB, and due to the way I interpreted the linq implementation. Since the former is the result of initial bulk-filling the data store, this means that the problem is solved.

On the 'negative' part of the solution: I would have preferred a solution that involved serializable cursors or something like that... this 'take' solution has to iterate the b-tree over and over again. If someone has an answer for this, please let me know.

-Stefan.

Comment: 1) Since are always ordering from the start of an id (which is presumably indexed), then I don't see where you are "iterating" the b-tree other than 100 items from the id of and index.  Not sure how else it would get 100 of these...

Comment: 2) Your question mentioned multiple readers.  Using the way you are doing it, what is preventing two different readers from processing the same record?

Comment: @CraigWilson It doesn't; I just enumerate the same collection for each "process" (e.g. an index, etc). Which is to be honest something that I would like to do concurrent, but actually I just solved that part of the puzzle 5 minutes ago :-) MongoDB has the brilliant thing that you can connect to individual replica sets and do the query. If you have as many instances of the process as the number of replica sets, you can simply enumerate one replica set per instance of your process. Actually that is the the complete solution I was looking for. BTW:This ability is a brilliant USP for MongoDB imho.

Comment: @CraigWilson BTW I don't really care about 100 or 500 or whatever batch size. I would prefer MongoDB to just give me whatever batch size is convenient- which is probably a single page in the B-tree. The cursor is then the page id. The '>=x take y' is just an inconvenient way of telling MongoDB to 'give me a cursor that's forever persistent'... If MongoDB implements the B-tree with linked lists (B+-tree) using the former approach is quite inefficient... Not sure if that was your question though?

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding why you think the '>=x take y' is inconvenient. That is how we tell people to implement paging.  It will seek to the correct record in the index and grab the next 100: pretty efficient.  Regardless, we do have support for tailable cursors(http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tailable+Cursors).  They are only supported on capped collections, which probably doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: @CraigWilson Thx. To be honest I think it's just because I'm used to our own NoSQL implementation. In this particular case we store [file id/ptr] for each server and have the ability to retrieve a batch with a size limit (e.g. 16 MB) regardless of the nr of elements. Since in our case file pointers are persistent, we use this as 'vector enumerator' and as you can imagine we get very high performance by doing it like this (1 seek + read/query/server so you can get 100 MB/s or more, even for 1 server). But as I said, doing the query per replica set give me [id] per server, which is fine as well.

Comment: P.S: for the sake of completeness, our use case is distributed indexing (search). We have our own (distributed) index/search implementation and want to create and maintain search indexes for certain slices of the dataset. Perhaps this context might explain a thing or two.